# Multiple fields not validated inside modal that are dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm validating fields inside modal popup,for single field it is working but if more than one field are appended at a time then validation does not takes place on those fields. Here we can see we add new field by adding add field button but those newly field did'nt get validated.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#newModalForm").validate();
    $('.form-control').each(function() {
        required($(this))
    });


    $(document).on('click', '#add_field', function(e) {
 $('#dynamic_div').html("<div class=form-group><label class=control-label col-md-3 for=email>Dynamic field 1:</label> <inputname=sfs type=text class=form-control></div> <div class=form-group><label class=control-label col-md-3 for=email>Dynamic field 2:</label><input name=ssf type=text class=form-control></div>");
        required($(this))
    });

    function required(el) {
        el.rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "This field is required",
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMyModal">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="addMyModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Stuff</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" id="newModalForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">A p Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pName" name="pName" placeholder="Enter a p name"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">Action:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="action" name="action" placeholder="Enter and action">
            </div>
          </div>
          
           
            <div class="col-md-9" id="dynamic_div">
              
            </div>
          
          
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveIt">Save</button>
            <button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-default">Add Field</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseIt" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need call `.each()` on the dynamically added elements as well.

Dynamically added elements are not in `DOM` `onload` so ideally you need to do wrap `.each()` in a function when you add more fields to your modal just call that function again to check for empty inputs

To handle submit and store data we can `.submit` on your modal form. Get all the data via `.serialize` method and send all your form data to the backend file via `ajax` request.

Run Snippet below to see it working.

```js
$(function() {

  //Validate Data
  var validate = $("#newModalForm").validate()
  checkInput()

  //Add dynamic inputs
  $(document).on('click', '#add_field', function(e) {
    $('#dynamic_div').html("<div class=form-group><label class=control-label col-md-3 for=email>Dynamic field 1:</label> <input name=sfs type=text class=form-control></div> <div class=form-group><label class=control-label col-md-3 for=email>Dynamic field 2:</label><input name=ssf type=text class=form-control></div>");

    //Required  Dynamic Input
    checkInput()
  });

  //Validate all inputs
  function checkInput() {
    $('.form-control').each(function() {
      required($(this))
    });
  }

  //Required field message
  function required(el) {
    el.rules("add", {
      required: true,
      messages: {
        required: "This field is required",
      }
    });
  }

  //Submit form modal
  $('#newModalForm').on('submit', function(e) {

    //Prevent default submit behaviour
    e.preventDefault()

    //Store all the form modal form data 
    var data = $(this).serialize()

    //Check all fieild have data
    if (validate.errorList.length == 0) {
      alert('All fields have value - Form will submit now')
      //Request to backend
      $.ajax({
        url: 'your_url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
          //do something on success
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
          //Handle errors
        }
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMyModal">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="addMyModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Stuff</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" method="post" id="newModalForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">A p Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pName" name="pName" placeholder="Enter a p name" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">Action:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="action" name="action" placeholder="Enter and action">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-9" id="dynamic_div">

          </div>


          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveIt">Save</button>
            <button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-default">Add Field</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseIt" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: :Thanks can you please tell where i can write submit handler for form

Comment: @user3653474 let me update my answer simplify the answer more with submit function as well. Thanks

Comment: Ok, Please add submit handler also

Comment: @user3653474 I have updated my answer to handle submit and store all data as and send  to the backend via ajax.